# How can I disable a button based on the value of a label

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to disable `button` based on the value of a `label`. 
Eg: If the `label` is equal to "Admin" then `button` is greyed out.

I thought you would do `.enable = false;` but the button is still available for an admin user.

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Main_Role_lbl.Text == "Admin")
    {
        LogTimebtn.Enabled = false;
        Holidaybtn.Enabled = false;
        //this.Controls.Add(LogTimebtn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you verified the conditional is entered? Your code says "Admin" with an uppercase A but you also said "admin" with a lowercase a (hint: use `string.ToUpper()` on both sides to do a case-insensitive comparison). **Never** assume anything about your data when dealing with user interfaces (e.g. if I named myself "aDminiSTR4tor"; you should *never* assume a user's name implies anything about permissions either).

Comment: What kind of application is this (Windows Forms, ASP.NET, something else)?  Instead of using `string.ToUpper()` for your comparison, consider using a mechanism that does a case insensitive string comparison like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_

Comment: Not enough information has been posted for us to give a solution.  Have you debugged?  Like @Elaskanator stated.. are you **sure** that the `if` statement is being entered?  Either `Enabled` attribute is the wrong attribute for disabling buttons, or the `if` statement is not being entered because of case of comparison.

Comment: @flydog57 this is a windows form application.  I have buttons disabled by using this idea in other parts of my project but not too sure why its not here.  It should of been "Admin" when i explained above aplogies.

Comment: I added a [WinForms] tag

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `if` statement.  Run your app from VS.  When it stops at the if statement (assuming you get there), look at the value of `Main_Role_lbl.Text`.  Is it exactly "Admin"?  Step to the next line.  Do you go into the `if`?  It's hard to debug over the internet like this

Comment: By the way, what causes that label's text to be set to "Admin".  Does it happen after (what I'm guessing is...) Form_Load?  Why not use that condition instead of a string compare to decide to enable/disable things

Comment: Like @Flydog57 suggests, use your debugger. This is an absolutely vital skill to learn as a developer. Never assume what your code is doing while tracking down bugs (otherwise why would there be a bug?). This might help: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017)

Comment: @flydog57 the label text will be set to a user role eg "admin".  so what ever role matches the username once logged in the label will be set to it via the sql server db.  hope that makes sense.   i used the ToolStripButton before and i can use this   if(Alerts_Role_lbl.Text != "Admin")
            {
                showLastWeekToolStrip.Enabled = false;     i thought it would be the same as a button ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the solution below.

```
    if (Main_Role_lbl.Text.ToLower() == "admin")
    {
        LogTimebtn.Enabled = false;
        Holidaybtn.Enabled = false;
        //this.Controls.Add(LogTimebtn);
    }
```